# firing Event for every RadioButton

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I'm creating a radio button in C# code for a WinRT application.

My code:

```
for(var l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
    RadioButton radio = new RadioButton();
    radio.Checked += (sender,arg)=>{ //sender };
    stackpanel.children.add(radio);
}
```

Now I add those radio buttons in page and I need to know which radio button is checked but when `event` fires it's sent to me only the last button. How do I make an event for every button so that when someone checks `Button 1` I can send a message box: "you checked button 1"?

Comment: Do you want a server side event or a client side event?\

Comment: @User2012384: i don't think that it's ASP.NET. Why can't you simply cast the `sender` argument to `RadioButton`? Then you have all you need, f.e. the `Name` or the `Tag` property.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oppps, you're correct, I overlooked..

Comment: It's a windows 8.1 project it has some page xaml , i don't understand what do u mean with server or client side

Comment: Tim Schmelter   /  Sender It's RadioButton it's send correctly the tag in event but send only from the last radibutton that  i generatet in for loop , not from others only from the last radibutton

Comment: @adasdasdsad:  You are clearly creating multiple instances and all use the same event handler which is no problem.

Comment: @adasdasdsad did you debug to see it sends last radio always? Or you are saying that based on some output by Checked event handler? What are you doing inside `Checked` event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CheckChangedEvent. Try to use this in your for-loop:

```
     RadioButton radio = new RadioButton();
                 radio.Name = "Button" + l;
                 radio.CheckedChanged += Radio_CheckedChanged;
```

And then when the event is triggered do the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This will trigger all changes to the CheckedState - even unchecking
    /// </summary>
    private void Radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) sender;//Cast the sender of the event back to RadioButton
        if (checkedRadioButton.Checked)//Only do this when checking - not on unchecking
        {
           MessageBox.Show($"You checked {checkedRadioButton.Name}", "Pressed"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sender It's RadioButton it's sending correctly the Tag in event but send only from the last radibutton that i generatet in for loop , not from others only from the last radiobutton

Comment: I don't get the point .. Why dont you just try the example I made ^^ ?